# SPListItem.BackwardLinks equivalent in CSOM, JSOM, or REST?

Tags: rest, client-object-model, splistitem, list-item

In the Server API for **SPListItem** there is a property called [BackwardLinks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.backwardlinks(v=office.15).aspx) that returns a collection of items that link to the item.  I don't see the same property in CSOM, JSOM, or REST.

Is there a way to get the BackwardLinks in CSOM, JSOM, REST, or some other way?

Is there a way in the UI to see this information for a list item?